# CSS place in circle first letter of the name

Tags: css

I'm making a website where I have some contacts and near every contact name I'm trying to get their initials and place it in a circle next to it like in the image below:

[image: A contact name with their initials in a circle next to their name]

Is it possible to make this with CSS?

I have tried it with `:first-letter` pseudo-class but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to get the first letters through JavaScript and then style it with CSS.

Comment: Creating the circle itself can be done with CSS, but getting the first letter from both first and last name can not. You should use something like jQuery to pick the first letters automatically and jiggle with it.

Comment: you will need some `JS` http://jsfiddle.net/82Ebt/80/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Since you stored those names, then when you extract them you can as well extract first-letter of each words/names and store them in a [data- attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

It is more a server-side (or javascript) job than CSS.

exemple with pseudo:

```css
[data-letters]:before {
  content:attr(data-letters);
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:1em;
  width:2.5em;
  height:2.5em;
  line-height:2.5em;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:plum;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-right:1em;
  color:white;
  }
```

```html
<p data-letters="MN"> My Name</p><!-- or whatever structure you used -->
```

Comment: how can i get then the first letter with javascript?

Comment: Grate idea with the data attribute!

Comment: This is worth a coffee.

Comment: after several years of frontend development I still see things I've never seen before

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/82Ebt/162/) is another way of doing this, I have modified a link given in a comment above, although some of the answers suggested above are quite shorter. This approach is very basic and simple to understand for beginners:

```js
$('h1').each(function() {
  var str = $(this).text();
  var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g);
  
  var acronym = matches.join('');
  
  $(this).prepend('<span><i>' + acronym + '</i></span>');
  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

h1 span {
  background: rgba(155, 79, 243, 0.74);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  align-items:center;
  color: rgba(233, 236, 237, 0.78);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
h1 span i{
  width:max-content;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Morbi metus</h1>
<h1>yorbi fasetus</h1>
<h1>test tessdfa</h1>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This can't be done ONLY with CSS, you'll need to modify some HTML at least (or use JS), let me explain :**

HTML, adding a title attribute :

```
<div class="my-circle" title="KM"></div>
<div class="name">Kwstas Mixopoulos</div>
```

CSS :

```
.my-circle {
    content: attr(title);
}
```

*But only with CSS, you can't have first letters from an element text node and put it in a content property.*

**If you can't modify HTML, you'll have to use a JS based solution.**

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you have access to the first name and last name. Using that, I have written this code which will take the first letter from First name and last name and apply to your profile image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var firstName = $('#firstName').text();
  var lastName = $('#lastName').text();
  var intials = $('#firstName').text().charAt(0) + $('#lastName').text().charAt(0);
  var profileImage = $('#profileImage').text(intials);
});



#profileImage {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #512DA8;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="firstName">King</span>
<span id="lastName">Singh</span>
<div id="profileImage"></div>
```